# sieve of Eratosthenes C++ algorithm

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement this algorithm and I have having a hard time working out the algorithm to work for finding the prime numbers up to 1000. I don't really understand but my code is not giving me the correct output, if you can suggest a way I should change my code I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n);

int main() {
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
    if( isPrime(i)) cout << "This number " << i <<  " is a prime. " << endl;
  }
}

bool isPrime(int n){
  if(n <= 1){
    return false;
  }
  if(n == 2){
    return true;
  }
  for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    if(n % i == 0){
        return false;   
    }else{
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the sieve of Eratosthenes :)

Comment: You're returning `true` from `isPrime()` the first time *any* number doesn't divide `n` evenly. For example, for `15`, you'd return `true` when `15 % 2 != 0`

Comment: Only return `true` at the *end* of the function, after the `for` loop, if nothing's caused a `false` return. That said, as @kaktusito says, this isn't the Sieve algorithm at all.

Comment: Moreover, you don't need to divide a number till `n` (itself). A number that's not divisible by numbers till its square root won't divide by anything above.

Comment: Thanks to @asgs for the root hint.

Comment: What do I have to changne to make it into sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: @Wolfgang-1: The Sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't use an `isPrime` function at all -- rather, it marks off numbers in an array.

Comment: Your code shouldn't contain `isPrime` function. The sieve idea is to create a set of (odd) numbers and then to remove from this set all the multiples of 3, 5, 7 etc. For a good explanation with pictures please look here: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your isPrime function

```
bool isPrime(int n){
  if(n <= 1){
    return false;
  }
  if(n == 2){
    return true;
  }
  for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    if(n % i == 0){
        return false;   
    }
    else{
        return true; /* this line is very dangerous. When there is odd number it is not divisible by two so the control goes to else block and you get every odd number as your prime number */
    }
  }
}
```

Instead use this

```
bool isPrime(int n){
  if(n <= 1){
    return false;
  }
  if(n == 2){
    return true;
  }
  for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    if(n % i == 0){
        return false;   
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

For Sieve Of Erastosthenes 
try this code it may help

```
int b;
    cout << "Enter upper limit" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    bool *x;
    x = new bool[b];
    x[2] = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < b; i++)
    {
        int count = 2;
        if (x[i])
        {
            cout << i << endl;

            while (i*count < b)
            {
                x[i*count] = false;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you should explain to the OP how it would help? :)

Comment: I agree, can you explain the last part of your code

Comment: @Wolfgang-1 Sieve Of Eratosthenes.... it starts by printing 2 and making all the multiples of 2 i.e. 4,6,8... etc as false. ie x[4]=false,x[6]=false and soon. then it continue for loop of 3. it checks for x[3] and prints 3 as x[3] is not set to false. so it will print 3 and make all the multiples of 3 as false i.e x[6],x[9],x[12]... etc are set to false. then the  loop starts for x[4], since x[4] is already false, the if block is skipped, then after loop startd for 5,6,7 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your decision inside the `for` loop inside `isPrime()` is wrong. This is a criterion to terminate the loop:

```
if(n % i == 0){
```

but the `else`part is no reason to terminate. You have to wait until the `for` loop finished. Like this:

```
for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    if(n % i == 0){
        // Here, we are sure that n can be divided by any other numbers than 1 and n.
        return false;   
    }
}

// Here, we are sure that n cannot be divided by any number 2 .. (n-1).
return true;
}
```

By the way, you only have to check until the square root of n. You can spare the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `isPrime` function.

Your `isPrime` function says if the the first value of `i` (i.e 2) is not divided by `n` then return true. So for eg. 21, 27 etc are also counted as a prime number.

You can use a flag variable in the `isPrime` function and used it to determine whether the n is prime or not. Like this

```
boolean prime = true;
for(int counter = 2; counter <= number / 2; counter++) {
    if(number % counter == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
}
return prime;
```

I don't think this is `Sieve of Eratosthenes` algorithm. If you want to implement this algorithm then you can read from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).